# Values will not insert in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array of dates from session to be stored to the database. I used foreach to save each array value to the database.

```
    $guestID = $_SESSION['guestID'];

$reservationQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(reservationID) AS resID FROM reservation WHERE guestID = $guestID;") OR die("Error in SELECT: ".mysqli_error($conn));

$reservationID = mysqli_fetch_array($reservationQuery);

    foreach($_SESSION['noOfRooms'] AS $type => $rooms){
        foreach($_SESSION['dates'] AS $dates){
            $reserves = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO roomreservation (reservationID, date_scheduled, roomDetailsNo, roomNo)
                                                SELECT $reservationID[resID], '$dates', roomDetailsNo, roomNo
                                                FROM rooms
                                                WHERE roomDetailsNo = $type AND room_status = 'available' LIMIT $rooms[0];") OR die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE rooms SET room_status = 'reserved' WHERE roomDetailsNo = $type AND room_status = 'available' LIMIT $rooms[0];") OR die("ERROR in Update: ".mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

When I ran the program. the table roomreservation was empty and did not save any of the values I inserted. I don't see the problem. can anyone help me?

Comment: echo "INSERT INTO roomreservation (reservationID, date_scheduled, roomDetailsNo, roomNo)
                                                SELECT $reservationID[resID], '$dates', roomDetailsNo, roomNo
                                                FROM rooms
                                                WHERE roomDetailsNo = $type AND room_status = 'available' LIMIT $rooms[0];"; exit; and run in myphpmyadmin  with check error;

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Kindly show what do you have in array. i.e. noOfRooms

Comment: it's ok, it's now working properly, I'm not sure why or how but it's now functioning